# Forms authentication fails for every postback in a website which uses ARR to load balance

Tags: iis-7, load-balancing, arr

I have to say I am very new to this whole field. 
**Scenario.** 
I have 2 website a.com and login.com (a uses this to authenticate) So unauthenticated user who tries to access a.com will get redirected to login.com. Now i have a server farm using ARR and I have exact same copy of both the websites in the two different servers in the server farm. Also the session is stored in the database. Now my problem is for my every post back it redirects to login.com saying that i am not authenticated. i checked the database and only one session id is getting written there Can someone help me figure out what am i doing wrong? All these websites have the same application id in all the servers